Slipt a low poly terrain into multiple blocks

I want to split the whole terrain into 100 blocks on the X and Y axis. I added loop cuts but since the top has a lot of faces, it won't do it correctly.

these are the loop cuts I added
EDIT: added .blend file


If you can share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/, we can see whether our methods work

thanks for letting me know, i added it

Could you explain how you would like to manipulate these "blocks" ? From your comment, I understand that "blocks" could be "objects". In this case, it is very different from a "simple" loop cut, and more like a boolean operation perhaps if you want to "split" the original object into parts.

I found a fix to my solution by using an array of planes and using the boolean subtraction
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2fMJOl2-_8

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
You can add a Grid, delete faces only to keep edges, then use this object with Knife Project :


this has made the terrain into multiple select-able portions but i can seem to split them from each other
